# Join two tables and show null in columns if column is not present

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as follows.

#### stages:

```
stageid     stagename     is_corrected
   1           abc              1
   2           xyz              1
   3           aaa              0
   4           bbb              1
```

#### responses:

```
stageid     teamid      diffscore      
   1           1            10
   1           2            12
   1           3            15
   2           1            12
   2           2            13
   2           3            16
   2           4            14
```

I am trying to join them and show a joined table where `is_corrected` = 1. Here is the query I tried:

#### Query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.stagename, 
    t2.diffscore 
FROM 
    stages t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            diffscore, 
            teamid, 
            stageid 
        FROM 
            responses as t2
    ) as t2 ON t2.stageid = t1.stageid 
    OR t1.stageid = NULL 
WHERE 
    t1.is_corrected = 1 
    AND (
        t2.teamid = 4 
        OR t2.teamid = NULL
    )
```

#### Expected Result:

```
stagename      diffscore
   abc            NULL
   xyz            14
   bbb            NULL
```

#### Output:

```
stagename      diffscore
   xyz            14
```

Comment: can you please make a sqlfiddle to check query???

Comment: @Narayan I need to show all stages rows where `is_corrected = 1` and attach `diffscore` column from other table.

Comment: there are several `diffscore` which one you need to pick?

Comment: @FrayneKonok the one where `teamid = 4`

Comment: `teamid` has several value, you need just the `teamid = 1`??

Comment: @FrayneKonok yes only where `teamid = 4`. Sorry I said `1` first.

Comment: Check me out now, I update my answer.

Comment: Sir, I update my answer with a brand new query, Please check this out, may be it will make some good result for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    s.stageid, 
    s.stagename, 
    IFNULL(
        (
            SELECT 
                diffscore 
            FROM 
                responses 
            WHERE 
                s.stageid = stageid 
                AND (
                    teamid = 1
                    OR teamid IS NULL
                )
            LIMIT 1
        ), 
        0
    ) AS diffscore 
FROM 
    stages s 
WHERE 
    is_corrected = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    stagename, 
    t2.teamid 
FROM 
    stages t1 
    LEFT JOIN responses as t2 ON t1.stageid = t2.stageid 
WHERE 
    t1.is_corrected = 1 
    AND (
        t2.teamid = 13 
        OR t2.teamid IS NULL
    );
```

Comment: Yes it was my dumb mistake to use `=` instead of `IS` but still it is showing the same table.

Comment: Now remove OR condition to check teamid is NULL...It may help you out